# Sizing in Android layouts?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, android-layout

This is confusing me to the end of the world. I have a 4.5inch screen at 480x800px and I don't know what the DPI is for the screen, or any screen for that matter. Let's say I wanna do this:

[image]

And each red box would be a picture going from one side of the screen to the other, and the blue box would be some other thing (ImageButton or something). How can I tell what the screen's DPI is and how many pixels to set each picture to?! This should be simple but it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

**1. define the layout in xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:weightSum="7"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="2"

        android:text="button"    
    />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#FFF"
    />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#0FF"
    />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#F0F"
    />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#FF0"
    />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

** 2. Define the layout in code **

I'm not gonna go into details here, you can get all the numbers from [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is highly encouraged that you don't hard code the hights and widths for things. The different possible densities your application could be running on is the exact reason why you want to avoid manually setting the size of things.

Instead you can use things like wrap_content and fill_parent. You can create what you are after with a LinearLayout with the ImageButton and all of the ImageViews inside of that. Then you can set your ImaveViews to have height ="wrap_content" and width ="fill_parent". That way now matter what screen you are on they will always get displayed at full width and the same height as the picture you are displaying.

[Read about Layouts here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) pay special attention to the section on LinearLayouts.

[find an example here](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/4/) to start with.

Also consider the fact that not every device your app may run on is as large as yours. Lots of them won't have room for 6 rows to be on the display unless you want your heights to get way too small to be useful. If you must have this many rows displayed you'll have to also wrap your LinearLayout in a ScrollView.